# Type signature of num to double?

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I'm just starting *Learn You a Haskell for Great Good*, and I'm having a bit of trouble with type classes. I would like to create a function that takes any number type and forces it to be a double.

My first thought was to define

```
numToDouble :: Num -> Double
```

But I don't think that worked because `Num` isn't a *type*, it's a *typeclass* (which seems to me to be a set of types). So looking at `read`, shows `(Read a) => String -> a`. I'm reading that as "read takes a string, and returns a thing of type `a` which is specified by the user". So I wrote the following

```
numToDouble :: (Num n) => n -> Double
numToDouble i = ((i) :: Double)
```

Which looks to me like "take thing of type n (must be in the `Num` typeclass, and convert it to a Double". This seems reasonable becuase I can do `20::Double`

This produces the following output

```
Could not deduce (n ~ Double)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
from the context (Num n)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  bound by the type signature for numToDouble :: Num n => n -> Double
```

I have no idea what I'm reading. Based on what I can find, it seems like this has something to do with polymorphism?

**Edit:**

To be clear, my question is: Why isn't this working?

Comment: You can write this function, but it requires you enable `RankNTypes`: `toDouble :: (forall n . Num n => n) -> Double; toDouble i = i`. This may not behave like you want it to, you can write `toDouble 1` but not `toDouble (1 :: Int)`, because the arguement to the function must be fully polymorphic - the type must be "any type in `Num`"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you can say "20::Double" is that in Haskell an integer literal has type "Num a => a", meaning it can be any numeric type you like.

You are correct that a typeclass is a set of types. To be precise, it is the set of types that implement the functions in the "where" clause of the typeclass. Your type signature for your numToDouble correctly expresses what you want to do.

All you know about a value of type "n" in your function is that it implements the Num interface. This consists of +, -, *, negate, abs, signum and fromInteger. The last is the only one that does type conversion, but its not any use for what you want.

Bear in mind that Complex is also an instance of Num. What should numToDouble do with that? The Right Thing is not obvious, which is part of the reason you are having problems.

However lower down the type hierarchy you have the Real typeclass, which has instances for all the more straightforward numerical types you probably want to work with, like floats, doubles and the various types of integers. That includes a function "toRational" which converts any real value into a ratio, from which you can convert it to a Double using "fromRational", which is a function of the "Fractional" typeclass.

So try:

```
toDouble :: (Real n) => n -> Double
toDouble = fromRational . toRational
```

But of course this is actually too specific. GHCI says:

```
Prelude> :type fromRational . toRational
fromRational . toRational :: (Fractional c, Real a) => a -> c
```

So it converts any real type to any Fractional type (the latter covers anything that can do division, including things that are not instances of Real, like Complex) When messing around with numeric types I keep finding myself using it as a kind of generic numerical coercion.

**Edit:** as leftaroundabout says,

```
realToFrac = fromRational . toRational
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't "convert" anything per se in Haskell. Between specific types, there may be the possibility to convert – with dedicated functions.

In your particular example, it certainly *shouldn't* work. `Num` is the class<sup>1</sup> of all types that can be *treated* as numerical types, and that *have* numerical values in them (at least integer ones, so here's one such conversion function [`fromInteger`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3afromInteger)).

But these types can apart from that have any other stuff in them, which oftentimes is not in the reals and can thus not be approximated by `Double`. The most obvious example is [`Complex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Complex.html).

The particular class that has *only* real numbers in it is, suprise, called [`Real`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t%3aReal). What is indeed a bit strange is that its method is a conversion `toRational`, since the rationals don't quite cover the reals... but they're dense within them, so it's kind of ok. At any rate, you can use that function to implement your desired conversion:

```
realToDouble :: Real n => n -> Double
realToDouble i = fromRational $ toRational i
```

Incidentally, that combination `fromRational . toRational` is already a standard function: [`realToFrac`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3arealToFrac), a bit more general.

---

Calling type classes "sets of types" is kind of ok, much like you can often get away without calling any kind of collection in maths a set – but it's not really correct. The most problematic thing is, you can't really say some type is *not* in a particular class: type classes are open, so at any place in a project you could declare an instance for some type to a given class.

Comment: Some languages use `Real` as a synonym for `Float` or `Double`. Interestingly Haskell's `Rational` has a larger number of elements than these `Real` types. Don't tell Cantor. :)

Comment: Using `Real` as a synonym for `Double` is an abomination.  Real numbers have a lot of nice properties that floating point numbers don't have.  So let's use the right words for the the right things.

Comment: @augustss: I agree it's not nice to call `Double` "real", but OTOH it's pretty much the best fit we have... apart from advanced stuff such as [AERN](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/AERN-Real) implements, of course; but that's hardly feasible to use in most applications. Definitely, `Double` is better suited for real numbers than `Rational`.

Comment: I have nothing against using `Double` for numerical computations (if you understand what you're doing), I just object to people calling them real numbers, because they are certainly not.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as numeric casts in Haskell.  When you write `i :: Double`, what that means isn't "cast `i` to `Double`"; it's just an assertion that `i`'s type is `Double`.  In your case, however, your function's signature also asserts that `i`'s type is `Num n => n`, i.e., any type `n` (chosen by the caller) that implements `Num`; so for example, `n` could be `Integer`.  Those two assertions cannot be simultaneously true, hence you get an error.

The confusing thing is that you *can* say `1 :: Double`.  But that's because in Haskell, a numeric literal like `1` has the same meaning as `fromInteger one`, where `one :: Integer` is the `Integer` whose value is one.

But that only works for numeric literals.  This is one of the surprising things if you come to Haskell from almost any other language.  In most languages you can use expressions of mixed numeric types rather freely and rely on implicit coercions to "do what I mean"; in Haskell, on the other hand you have to use functions like `fromIntegral` or `fromRational` all the time.  And while most statically typed languages have a syntax for casting from one numeric type to another, in Haskell you just use a function.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be 100% clear, the problem is

```
(i) :: Double
```

This does not *convert* `i` to a `Double`, it *demands* that `i` *already is* a `Double`. That isn't what you mean at all.

The type signature for your function is correct. (Or at least, it means exactly what you think it means.) But your function's implementation is wrong.

If you want to convert one type of data to another, you have to actually *call a function* of some sort.

Unfortunately, `Num` itself only allows you to convert an `Integer` to any `Num` instance. You're trying to convert something that isn't necessarily an `Integer`, so this doesn't help. As others have said, you probably want `fromRational` or similar...